# Metrics on $\mathbb{N}$ such that $(\mathbb{N}, d)$ and $(\mathbb{N}, d')$ are not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I want to find two metrics $d$ and $d'$ on $\mathbb{N}$ such that $(\mathbb{N}, d)$ and $(\mathbb{N}, d')$ are not homeomorphic, but I'm having trouble doing so. I've tried using the discrete metric as this often has very different properties to the usual metric, and can be used to show it for $\mathbb{R}$ but I can't seem to get it to work for $\mathbb{N}$. I've also tried considering topological properties such as compactness, connectedness, etc, but again the two metrics always seem to have the same properties, and also considered sequences.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, with the usual metric, are not homeomorphic.

Comment: Make one metric where $x_n = n$ converges to $0$, and another where any convergent sequence is eventually constant.

Comment: Look into [$p$-adic metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number).

Comment: @kccu ... interesting.  Certainly the identity map from the $2$-adic to the $3$-adic metric on $\mathbb Z$ is not a homeomorphism.  But how do we show that there is no other map that is a homeomorphism?

Comment: @GEdgar Every convergent sequence in $\mathbb{N}$ with the usual metric is eventually constant. This is not so for the $p$-adic metrics. That's enough for OP's purposes.

Comment: OK I understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A concrete example of Ethan's idea:

$d_1(n,m)=1$ for $n \neq m$ (the discrete metric), which has the property that any convergent sequence is eventually constant.

$d_2(0,n)=\frac{1}{n}$ for $n \neq 0$ and $d_2(n,m)= |\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}|$ for $n,m$ non-zero and distinct. Then $x_n = n$ converges to $0$, and such a non-trivial sequence does not exist under $d_1$, so the topologies are different (also $(\mathbb{N}, d_2)$ is compact, while $(\mathbb{N}, d_1)$ is not).

Comment: This has really helped, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let  $A$  be a countable subset of any metric space you like. Transfer the metric to $\mathbb{N}$ with a bijection that establishes the countability.